# show all information in the main process console

Tags: python, console, process

I got a program (written in python) who starts several processes.
Now I want that information (errors, warnings, prints etc.) from all started processes are displayed in the main process console.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use pipes with the subprocess module see

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Comment: That would be helpful to know along with some code to further narrow down your issue.